# zip deflated 0% ? Why no compression?

Tags: linux, unix, compression, zip, command

I'm trying to zip the content of a folder that contains 4 big files, very, very similar. So I expect the size to be reduced.

Here's the command I'm using on linux/fedora:

```
zip -9 myarchive.zip -r myfolder -P mypassword
```

I get the response:

```
adding: myfolder/ (stored 0%)
adding: myfolder/Program1.exe (deflated 0%)
adding: myfolder/Program2.exe (deflated 0%)
adding: myfolder/Program3.exe (deflated 0%)
adding: myfolder/Program4.exe (deflated 0%)
```

Then I get the archive, which is approx the same size as my original folder.

It seems that no compression is occurring at all. Why?

Comment: What happens when you omit `-P mypassword`?

Comment: Not all data could be compressed.

Comment: it's the same when I omit -P mypassword.

Comment: "Not all data could be compressed". Ok but it seems that the compression was 0% (otherwise, what does "deflated 0%" mean?). And as I said, the 4 files are very very similar so compression should occur. Or does zip only compress each file and not the folder as a whole? This would be very sad.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unlike `tar` + `gzip`, `zip` uses a new compression table for each file, so even if the four files were identical, it would try to compress each individually.

Technically, `tar` also sees each file but it strings them together into one long input for `gzip`, so the compression step works on one huge input which is why `tar` + `gzip` usually yields a smaller result than `zip`.

The question is why your `exe` files can't be compressed. `exe` files usually contains large amounts of easily compressible data, so they should shrink ("deflate") by at least 30%. Maybe the files are encrypted or obfuscated; these processes make the result hard to compress.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense then, if zip compresses individually each file. The files are self extractable exe, they contain a small executable + a big zipped library of dll files + some pictures. Images and libraries are already compressed and are almost the same for each file.

Answer (score 4):

Deflated 0% means that it did try to compress, but got effectively no compression.  As noted, the zip format cannot take advantage of similarity between different entries.  tar + gzip can, but even then only if the similarities end up less than 32K bytes away from each other.  Other formats can exploit longer distance similarities, such as xz.

It is normal for uncompressed executables to compress by 30% to 50%, which means that your executables are either a) compressed by something like [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/), b) they are self-extracting compressed data, where the decompressor is stored ahead of the compressed data, c) they are very short executables with a lot of compressed data, or d) they are mostly encrypted.

Answer (score 3):

Aaron is correct. According to `Wikipedia`, the `ZIP` format compresses before it archives, so similarities among different files doesn't help compression.

Are you really trying to compress `.exe` files? Somehow I doubt that's your actual file type.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#Advantages_and_disadvantages .

Comment: Thanks for your input and for the link. Yes my files are self extractable exe files (see my reply to Aaron). Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Some files cannot be compressed, in particular if their entropy is high. This happens when the statistical distribution of bytes is even (e.g. when byte 0 appear as often as byte 1 as byte 2...). This happens for already compressed contents. Some video or audio formats fall into that category.

Comment: I think each file has a high entropy, but they are very similar. There's probably less than 1% difference between two given files. So there is a lot of redundancy when considering the whole folder.

Comment: And what does "deflated 0%" means? I forgot to ask that in the original post. Thanks for your help.